# Need to scrape data from asp.net site with pagination using PHP CURL

Tags: php, asp.net, curl, web-scraping

We need to scrape data from asp.net site with pagination.

And send to the CURL post fields but not able to get 2nd page it's always return page 1.

See the link for pagination 2 & 3 : http://prntscr.com/og8pha

So please let me know how we can get the data 2nd and 3 rd page using CURL.

Please let me know if you want to more code to check.

Thanks in advance

We tried with this :

```
$post_data = [
        '__EVENTTARGET' => urlencode('ctl00$MainContent$GridView1'),
        '__EVENTARGUMENT' => urlencode('Page$2'),
    ];

$data = [
        'link'=> "SITE_URL",
        'cookiesession' => 1,
        'cookiefile' => $cookiefile,
        'post_data' => $post_data,
        'outputfile' => '',
        'referer' => '',
        'curl_timeout' => '',
        'follow_location' => 1
    ];
    $res = lib_curl($data);  
    $cookiefile = implode(' ',$res['cookiefile']);
    $res_data = $res['response'];
```

lib_curl() is function for call the curl request.

Comment: Is there any one can give me the solution for this issue i tried from last couple of hours but still not able to find the solution. 
So would you please let me know the solution if any one facing this issue in past ?